# How to adjust for Status Bar in Expo and NativeBase

Tags: react-native, expo, statusbar, native-base

I have a Expo app where I am using NativeBase Library (https://nativebase.io/)

For some reason the app is not adjusting for the Status Bar.
The displayed widget draws around the Status Bar area instead of starting the drawing right under the Status Bar which is normally the case.

What can I do to adjust for the Status Bar height within this Expo app using the NativeBase library?

[image]

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Box, Text, VStack, HStack, Checkbox, Divider, Heading, Center, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'native-base';

export default function App() {

  var data = [
    {
      id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
      title: "First Item",
    },
    {
      id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
      title: "Second Item",
    },
    {
      id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
      title: "Third Item",
    },
  ]
  return (
    

    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1}>
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Box px={5} py={2} rounded="md" my={2} bg="primary.300">
            {item.title}
          </Box>
          
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Constants.statusBarHeight` of `import Constants from 'expo-constants';`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import {
  NativeBaseProvider,
  Box,
  Text,
  VStack,
  HStack,
  Checkbox,
  Divider,
  Heading,
  Center,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'native-base';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  var data = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
    },
  ];
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <Center flex={1}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Box px={5} py={2} rounded="md" my={2} bg="primary.300">
                {item.title}
              </Box>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </Center>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: import Constants from 'expo-constants'; is deprecated

Comment: I don't think that is deprecated. This is the one that is deprecated: import { Constants } from 'expo'

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `NativeBase` Provider inside a view and give it a `flex of 1` and `marginTop` of `StatusBar.currentHeight`

As shown below

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import {
  NativeBaseProvider,
  Box,
  Text,
  VStack,
  HStack,
  Checkbox,
  Divider,
  Heading,
  Center,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'native-base';

export default function App() {
  var data = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
    },
  ];
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <Center flex={1}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Box px={5} py={2} rounded="md" my={2} bg="primary.300">
                {item.title}
              </Box>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </Center>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: currentHeight constant is only available in Android...any work around for ios? reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#currentheight-android

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look to SafeAreaContext component?
Link: [Expo SafeAreaContext](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/)

It allows your content to not get under the notch.

If you know it, and it doesn't fit your needs, you could work on StatusBarHeight  setting:

```js
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
    
let statusbar = StatusBar.currentHeight
    
return(<View style={{marginTop: statusbar}}
```

Comment: currentHeight constant is only available in Android...any work around for ios? https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#currentheight-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this for spacing

**import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';**

**const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Box, Text, VStack, HStack, Checkbox, Divider, Heading, Center, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'native-base';
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';


export default function App() {
  const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();


  var data = [
    {
      id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
      title: "First Item",
    },
    {
      id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
      title: "Second Item",
    },
    {
      id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
      title: "Third Item",
    },
  ]
  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: headerHeight }}>
        <NativeBaseProvider>
          <Center flex={1}>
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Box px={5} py={2} rounded="md" my={2} bg="primary.300">
                {item.title}
              </Box>
              
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
          </Center>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
     </View>
  );
}
```